# WPF assigning border background from image resource

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to simulate a grid inventory system. I have this grid with some rows and cols. I have a resource that is an image. The error I'm getting is:

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Controls.Image' to 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'**

If I change my Image cast to ImageBrush then the project compiles but the exe crashes right away.

```
<Grid x:Name="MasterGrid" Margin="0">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="notepad" Source="notepad_16x16.jpg" />
    </Grid.Resources>

// create a border and set it's background image
Border border = new Border();
border.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
var img = (Image)MasterGrid.FindResource("notepad");
border.Background = img;

// add the border to the grid
Grid.SetRow(border, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(border, 1);
Grid.SetRowSpan(border, 1);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(border, 1);
InvGrid.Children.Add(border);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The border.Background is expecting a brush, and you're populating it with an image. You need to create an ImageBrush from the Image resource

```
border.Background = new ImageBrush((BitmapImage)FindResource("notepad"));
```

Your image resources should be defined as follows:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="notepad" UriSource="images/notepad_16x16.jpg" />
</Grid.Resources>
```

Comment: I need to do this in code though. This is all dynamic stuff.

Comment: That worked. What is the difference between Image that I was using and BitmapImage that you use? Also, I noticed in my code the RowSpan has to be 2. If it's 1 the border doesn't show up at all. If it's 2 then it shows up normally in 1 cell. I would have thought if RowSpan was 2 it would take up 2 rows but that's not the case. Why would that be?

Comment: The image class represents a control that displays an image. A BitmapImage provides an image source that can be used.  An <Image> requires a source.  The bitmap image is the source. (Derived from ImageSource).  In short, the reason your code wasn't working, is because you were trying to load a control resource, and assigning that as a Brush. 

In regards to the grid, the code you have should work fine.  Create a new question with the grid definition, and expected output.

Comment: On a related note, you may want to use an <ItemsControl> binding the ItemsSource to a collection of inventory items; setting the ItemsPanelTemplate to a <UniformGrid>, that way you don't have to keep track of the grid col / row of each item.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\... your path to the image\notepad_16x16.jpg"/>
    </Grid.Background>
```

this works for me without setting borders.

Comment: This is like a grid inventory where each "cell" can have it's own image that represents an item (like a health potion or something like that).